# ¿Pantalla completa en WebView - Youtube?

Tags: java, android, webview

El siguiente código hace su función a la perfección: Me lleva a youtube usando webview, es decir, sin salir de la aplicación y el vídeo se reproduce perfectamente. El problema es el siguiente: No puedo girarlo para ponerlo en pantalla completa.

He probado con dos móviles:

- Uno con 4.4.2: me da la opción de ponerlo en pantalla completa pero al darle no me hace ni caso.
- Otro con 6.0: ni me sale esa opción.

¿No es posible hacerlo? He buscado al respecto pero es algo ambigüo y era en otro idioma, a ver si alguna ha conseguido o sabe de este peculiar tema.

Éste es mi código:

```
public class Boxeo extends Fragment {

    WebView appWeb;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);

        String url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c";
        appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Cargamos el enlace definido
        appWeb.loadUrl(url);
        //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
        appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        appWeb.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        appWeb.onPause();
    }
}
```

ACTUALIZADO:

```
public class Boxeo extends Fragment {

    WebView appWeb;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);

    //poniendo _popup detras de "watch" en el enlace de un video, se veria en grande, pero solo 1 video.
        appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

      /*String url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c";

        //Habilitamos el javaScript
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); Para zoom

        //Cargamos el enlace definido
        appWeb.loadUrl(url);

        appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return v;*/


        String video = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
                + "</iframe>\n";
        appWeb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        appWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        appWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        appWeb.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        appWeb.setInitialScale(0);
        appWeb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        appWeb.loadData(video,"text/html","UTF-8");

        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        appWeb.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        appWeb.onPause();
    }


}
```

> 17453-17453/com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1, PID: 17453
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1.Videos.Boxeo.onCreateView(Boxeo.java:55)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Puedes ver este repo https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Comment: @RfMvs esto sería dificil me gustaría que en verdad se tuviera una solución, prueba lo que comenta x4mp73r

Comment: @RfMvs: `He buscado al respecto pero es algo ambigüo y era en otro idioma` ¿puedes compartir las fuentes de la información? tal vez otros usuarios puedan ayudarte.

Comment: En inglés, en stackoverflow, "full screen youtube android " en google y primer y segundo link, estoy siguiendo lo de x4mp73r que es prácticamente igual pero allí no explican nada y aquí espero su respuesta.

Comment: @RfMvs hola amigo ayer vi esta pregunta, iba a comentar que sinceramente me gustaría ver una solución pero creo que sería dificil realizar lo que deseas. Voy a buscar una posible opción que es una librería que utilicé en un proyecto...

Comment: Ah sí cierto, comentaste, me comentó x473mpr y me dió 3 soluciones. La 1a no sirve, ya la miré, y las otras 2 son iguales pero la última es la más completa y es la que no me sirve ya que se me queda en blanco la pantalla. Y vale, espero a ver si encuentras esa librería , muchas gracias :)

Comment: Estoy haciendo esto y nada... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723423/youtube-iframe-embed-full-screen mira a ver si te sirve a ti o algo y estoy poniendo algo mal

Comment: @Jorgesys al final nada? :(

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ver este [repo](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView)

O usar `iframe`:

```
String video = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c\"   allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>"

appWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
appWeb.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
appWeb.loadData(video , "text/html", "utf-8");
```

O prueba de esta forma:

```
String video = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
                + "</iframe>\n";
        appWeb.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        appWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        appWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        appWeb.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        appWeb.setInitialScale(0);
        appWeb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        appWeb.loadData(video,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Lo de string video (lo ultimo) tengo que sustituir todo por ese codigo? Lo he puesto, a ver si va, he sustituido lo del create por eso ultimo, veamos qué tal.

Comment: Se me crashea la App introduciendo lo último, que hago mal? Arriba esta actualizado con su correspondiente log

Comment: Estoy poniendo un poco de código para que no se me crashee y no lo hace pero no me sale nada.... cómo debo combinarlo para ver si funciona? Ese código no sé exactamente cómo colocarlo.

Comment: Cuando puedas me ayudarías mucho contestando estas últimas dudas sobre tu respuesta, un saludo.

Comment: Porque la repo que me pasaste es demasiado larga y tengo dudas en el iframe

Comment: @RfMvs Comentaste esta línea `appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
` Recuerda que ahí le dices a que webView le aplicas todo eso por medio de su ID. Descomenta esa parte y me dices

Comment: Lo he descomentado y he puesto el tocho último tal como estaba y me sale todo en blanco.

Comment: ¿Hace falta importar alguna librería ?